# Parse data from a pandas column containing dicts to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse data from a pandas column containing `dicts` to a new column. However, I get an `value error` when I attempt to do the following.

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({
                  'id': [0, 1, 2],
                  'str': [{'a':'1'},{'a':'2'},np.nan]
                 })

d['new_col'] = d.apply(lambda x: d['str'].str['a'] if pd.notnull(x) else x, axis=1)
```

Traceback:

```
/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1525     @final
   1526     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1527         raise ValueError(
   1528             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> d.apply(lambda x: d['str'].str['a'] if pd.notnull(x) else x, axis=1)
> ```

What is happening is that you are applying the function to each row of the DataFrame `d`, so `x` stands for each row (a `pd.Series`), not each dictionary (or NaN value) of the column 'str'. Since the truthiness of a Series is ambiguous the error is raised due to the boolean check `pd.notnull(x)`.

Try this instead

```
d['new_col'] = d['str'].apply(lambda x: x['a'] if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

Output:

```
>>> d

   id         str new_col
0   0  {'a': '1'}       1
1   1  {'a': '2'}       2
2   2         NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `apply` that will be slow on large datasets, but rather the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) accessor:

```
d['new_col'] = d['str'].str['a']
# or
d['new_col'] = d['str'].str.get('a')
```

Output:

```
   id         str new_col
0   0  {'a': '1'}       1
1   1  {'a': '2'}       2
2   2         NaN     NaN
```

Comment: I need a condition to check for `NaN`.

Comment: Yes, using the `str` accessor is definitely better here, it's simpler and more efficient, although it's not vectorized either ;) My point was just to explain OP why their attempt doesn't work and offer a similar solution

Comment: @kms why? `str` already handles NaN automatically. What would you want to do that is not described in the question?

Comment: @kms `str.get` and `str.__getitem__` does that automatically for you under the hood